# Background image in my header

Tags: html, css, background-image

How am I able to put a background image in my header on my website.  I'm having trouble sizing it the correct way and making it a background image.

An example would be this website:

http://crossfitweightlifting.com/

Thanks!

Comment: Please post what you have tried so far (hopefully some code) and what it is that isn't working for you.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow, please revise this : http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

I would have been good if you could share what you have currently but try to apply some css to the image in header as below

```
.header img {
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  min-width:100%;
}
```

this will try to make the image occupy the entire space.

Comment: actually this is a bad approach, its far better to use the `background-image` css attribute on `.header` incase you want to use an image in the header that would not want to inherit these properties..  and you were a bit hasty to answer without any context of what OP has to work with.

Answer (score 0):

just add this into your css:

```
header{
    background: url("yourImage.jpg") center center fixed;
    /*OPTIONAL*/
    -o-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -ms-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}
```